# Calling a Stored Procedure Within a Cursor Loop, Without Tripping the Continue Handler

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, handler

I am trying to call a Stored Procedure in MySQL within the loop of a Cursor.  The cursor behaves properly when doing an INSERT in the loop; but if I try to call a Stored Procedure, the continue Handler 'sets done = 1' and will exit the loop prematurely, after the first record is processed.  Any thoughts on how to work around this?  Thanks.

```
declare test_cursor cursor for 
       select projectid, projectdesc
         from tblProjects
        order by projectdesc;          

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

set done = 0;  
open test_cursor;

repeat

  fetch test_cursor into wprojectid, wprojectdesc;

  if not done then  

    insert into tblTest (a, b) values (wprojectid, wprojectdesc);   <--this would work
    call spTest(wprojectid, wprojectdesc, @retrn);                                    <--this trips the Handler after first loop

  end if;      

until done end repeat;

close test_cursor;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm NOT sure about it, but try to see if this code works or not ?

```
declare test_cursor cursor for 
       select projectid, projectdesc
         from tblProjects
        order by projectdesc;          

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;
DECLARE done_holder INT;


set done = 0;
open test_cursor;

repeat

  fetch trade_cursor into wprojectid, wprojectdesc;

  if not done then  

    set done_holder = done;
    insert into tblTest (a, b) values wprojectid, wprojectdesc;
    call spTest(a, b, @retrn);
    set done = done_holder;

  end if;      

until done end repeat;

close test_cursor;
```

Comment: That's close, this approach is similar but more elegant than my "set done = 0" force after calling the sp.  Still abending here.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution - the problem is that when the "call spTest..." function runs, then it will sometimes trip the "done" flag.  I'm setting a variable value through calling a function here sometimes.  So storing the value for "done" into a temp holder _before_ calling the function, and loading that value back into "done" right after the call corrects the issue.  Thanks Ehsan.

Comment: Thank you @user1399233! I could not understand why it was tripping after the first loop. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here - 'call spTest(a, b, @retrn);', try to change it with this one -

```
CALL spTest(wprojectid, wprojectdesc, @retrn);
```

so, your code can be like this -

```
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE wprojectid, wprojectdesc  INT;
  DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT projectid, projectdesc FROM tblProjects ORDER BY projectdesc;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

  SET done = 0;
  OPEN test_cursor;

  REPEAT
  FETCH test_cursor INTO wprojectid, wprojectdesc;
    IF NOT done THEN
      INSERT INTO tblTest (a, b) VALUES (wprojectid, wprojectdesc);
      CALL spTest(wprojectid, wprojectdesc, @retrn);
    END IF;
  UNTIL done
  END REPEAT;
  CLOSE test_cursor;
```

Comment: No, the problem not is what params are passed to the sp (ie the syntax of the sp), the problem is that calling of the sp sets the continue handler 'done' to 1, and the loop is exited.

Comment: Strange. I have tested, it works. Try to debug the code, possible there are other error issues. [Debugger for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) You can use trial version.

Comment: I think the problem actually is that when I pass a NULL as one of the IN params to my storedproc, the underlying INSERT abends because of a NOT NULL constraint, and the sp kicks out of the REPEAT loop. So the problem I was seeing was not real.  I'll continue my testing.  Thanks much.